# Is it possible to generate py.test test files in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

Let's say I have an `app.py` file with the following contents:

```
def foo():
    return 'bar'
```

Even with `py.test` set as a default test runner in PyCharm (`Settings -> Tools -> Python Integrated Tools`), PyCharm always generate `unittest`-like tests (`right-click on a function name -> Go To -> Test -> Create New Test`), eg.:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        self.fail()
```

I can change `Python Unit Test` template in `Setting -> Editor -> File and Code Templates`, but it only has effect when creating new file (`New -> Python File -> Kind: Python unit test`).

I would like the generated tests to be more `py.test`-like:

```
def test_foo():
    assert False
```

Even better would be to have proper `import`s already placed in:

```
from my_app import foo

def test_foo():
    assert False
```

Comment: I just stumbled into this one. I'd finally made the switch from unittest and was going insane trying to figure out why Generate Test wouldn't honour my setting to pytest as test runner. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible. Please vote for the corresponding feature request in PyCharms' bug tracker: [PY-15021](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15021).